# How do I show an availability calendar?

Tags: bookings

To recap: I previously built a site in Drupal 7 which showed the availability of two apartments for rent, using the [Availability Calendars](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars) module. The client easily selected dates and marked them available, booked or unavailable, and the result showed in 3 months of fullcalendar on the frontend.

I have now rebuilt the website in Drupal 8 and found out that the module has not been ported to Drupal 8. As suggested by the module developers, I have tried to rebuild the entire availability system using the [Booking and Availability Management Tools for Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/bat) module.

However, BAT proves extremely difficult to set up. I have successfully installed BAT and dependencies through Composer, then painstakingly followed the manual, setting up units and fields etc.

I have now managed to get to the point where I can select dates and mark them as available/booked/unavailable, but can't find a way to show this on the frontend of the site.

Any change I make (name of a unit, name of a type) results in the whole BAT system giving error screens. For example, the BAT's topmost item in *configuration*, *type group bundles* isn't mentioned in the manual, and if I dare create one, BAT just crashes.

How do I show the availability assigned to units in the back end, in a calendar on the front end?
What are type group bundles (they're not in the documentation) and why do they crash all settings 'lower' in the hierarchy?